# Socket.io - Socket connection between clients

Tags: javascript, connection, socket.io, client

Im looking form something to make socket connection between client, without pass through the server. Is there any node package to do this?. Server only send the other client socket, and the clients recieve and send data to each other..

Or, how can we make the implamantation. We need to make a server in client side, but we dont have node installed in the client..

Comment: That impossible.. Clients not able to find each other without pass through server.. Also, web browsers aren't equipped to act as server because that depends on OS configuration and firewall settings..

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that currently exists in some form is not currently part of socket.io. It is called WebRTC and is implemented in Chrome currently. It allows the browser to connect with other browsers.

http://www.webrtc.org

Answer (score 0):

The question is what kind of application is your client? If you are talking about ordinary webbrowsers you need to think about writing pluings (tough case).

If you are talking about clients you have more control then you should look at technique Puching the hole exploited by Skype or P2P apps.

http://it.slashdot.org/story/06/12/15/191205/how-skype-punches-holes-in-firewalls

In general the server is used for TCP sockets orchestration the acutall comunication go directly.